# Calculating Percentage value for a Group by value in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, group-by, percentage

I want to calculate Percentage of a value in Group by. My Table data

```
salesId   salesAmount   productName   salesTyp
-------   -----------   -----------   --------
      1         50.00   mouse         online
      2        100.00   mouse         shop
      3        150.00   mouse         shop
      4         50.00   mouse         shop
      5        100.00   keyboard      shop
      6         50.00   keyboard      online
```

The Out put i want to show like

```
productName   totalamount   percentageofonline
-----------   -----------   ------------------
      mouse           350                25.00
   keyboard           150                50.00
```

Here 4 mouse was sold (3 in shop and 1 in Online) so the percentage is 25.00
and 2 keyboard was sold (1 in shop and one in online) so the percentage is 50.00

Please help me to get it. I have created a [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/56da8/2) for table structure.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In a quick way :

```
WITH total AS (
    SELECT productName, sum(salesAmount) AS totalamount 
    FROM testSales 
    GROUP BY productName 
)
SELECT total.totalamount, total.productName, (
        SELECT count(*) 
        FROM testSales 
        WHERE salesTyp='online' 
            AND productName = total.productName
    )::float / count(*) * 100 as percentageofonline
FROM testSales, total 
WHERE testSales.productName = total.productName 
GROUP BY total.productName, total.totalamount
```

the first subrequest computes the total amount, the subrequest is used for the percentage.

There must be a more optimized way to do it but that does the job

Answer (score 2):

You can use [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/tutorial-window.html)

```sql
SELECT productname,
       totalamount,
       TO_CHAR(totalamount * 100 / SUM(totalamount) OVER (), 'fm90D00%') AS prc
FROM (
         SELECT productname,
                SUM(salesAmount) AS totalamount
         FROM sales
         GROUP BY productname
     ) AS t
```

At the 1 step we have subquery which generates sum by products. At the 2 step we sum all sums over all totals, to reach these - we omit `partition` and `order` key words in over function.

To check query - copy-paste result to author's sql fiddle